# How to keep an orientation of component object on faces of base objects?

Tags: add-on

I have a problem when I use Tissue tool to make face structure like on pictures below. I don't understand why component object change its orientation 90 degrees when face of base object is changing. Do you have some ideas?
[image][image]

Comment: There are [2 buttons](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/tissue.html#rotate-faces) in the Tissue add-on that allows you to rotate a single face. Or you can use the UV map (another option, *Rotation* section > *Rotation: Active UV*) which works with a *Mirror* modifier. Have a look here: https://youtu.be/9RDIQvBB8XQ?feature=shared&t=930

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!